# How to associate query with changing variable in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, post

I'm in need of a bit help. I'm trying to find out how to associate a specific query (deletion of a record) with not the id of a record, but the record with which another query (selection of a record) is echoed out.

This line of code totally works when the id is specified, but again I need it for the record that gets called, where the id can skip numbers if I delete a record.

```
    $querytwo = "DELETE FROM `paginas` WHERE id = 5";
```

I've got a table in my phpmyadmin database with columns 'id', 'pagetitle', 'toevoeging' (addition in Dutch) , 'message'. First one is an INT, rest are varchars/text.

This may be a stupid question, I'm sorry for that. I'm still new to PHP, and to programming in general.

Here is the code. I've commented on lines code to clarify. Thanks you!.

```
<?php 
        if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) //if the admin is active, forms can be written out.
        {
        echo '</nav>
          <br><br>  <div class="inlogscript">
         <form action="verstuurd.php" method="post">

            <input type="text" placeholder="Titel" method="POST" name="pagetitle" /><br><br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Toevoeging" method="POST" name="toevoeging" /><br><br>
            <textarea class="pure-input-1-2" placeholder="Wat is er nieuws?" name="message"></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Bevestigen" />
        </form></div>'; 
        }       
        ?>  
    <div class="mainContent">

<?php

    include_once("config.php"); //this is the database connection
    $query = "SELECT * FROM paginas "; //selects from the table called paginas
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {
        $pagetitle = $row['pagetitle'];
        $toevoeging = $row['toevoeging'];
        $message = $row['message'];

            echo '<article class="topcontent">' . '<div class="mct">' .  '<h2>' . "$pagetitle" .'</h2>' . '</div>' . "<br>" . 
            '<p class="post-info">'. "$toevoeging" . '</p>' .   '<p class="post-text">' . '<br>'. "$message" . '</p>' .'</article>' . '<div class="deleteknop">' . '<form method="post">
            <input name="delete" type="submit" value="Delete Now!">
            </form>' . '</div>' ;
        } //This long echo will call variables $pagetitle, $toevoeging and &message along with divs so they automatically CSS styled, 
         //along with a Delete button per echo that has the 3 variables

    $querytwo = "DELETE FROM `paginas` WHERE id = 5";  
    if (isset($_POST['delete'])) //Deletes the query if 'delete' button is clicked

        {
            $resulttwo = $mysqli->query($querytwo);  
        }

        ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Also here is the Insert INTO query of the records. Thanks again!

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO paginas (pagetitle,toevoeging, message)
VALUES ('$_POST[pagetitle]','$_POST[toevoeging]','$_POST[message]')";
//the insertion into the table of the database

if ($MySQLi_CON->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "";
} else {
    echo "Error: ". $sql . "" . $MySQLi_CON->error;
}
```

Comment: And what should be associated with what?

Comment: This code needs to be written so it knows which query is being selected.

"DELETE FROM `paginas` WHERE id = 5";

Like: "DELETE FROM 'paginas' WHERE id = $idofthepost";
But $idofthepost won't work. I need to do something else with it but I just don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

This won't be sufficient but, to begin with your echo :

```
echo '<article class="topcontent">
       <div class="mct">
        <h2>' . $pagetitle .'</h2>
       </div><br>
       <p class="post-info">'. $toevoeging . '</p>
       <p class="post-text"><br>'.$message.'</p>
      </article>
       <div class="deleteknop">
        <form method="post">';
         // you ll want to use $_POST["id"] array to delete :
   echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'">
         <input name="delete" type="submit" value="Delete Now!">
        </form>
       </div>' ;
```

Comment: That brings up an undefined variable error, how would I need to declare $row?

Comment: sorry I forgot the html `name` attribute, I've just edited it. Now `$_POST['id']` will no longer be undefined

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'm still not there yet but I got closer so thanks.